# Insert data into database from controller Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my **def Create funciton** in casting_controller. I create an Casting object and save it. this is ok, but i also want to create a LinkCastingToModel object, insert data to it from my controller, but when i check, the data is always nil. How can i insert data into it

```
def create
  @casting = Casting.new(casting_params)
  @casting.models_booked = 0
  link = LinkModelAndCasting.new
  link.client_id = @casting.id
  link.save
  # link_model_and_casting = LinkModelAndCasting.new(:casting_id => @casting.id)
  # link_model_and_casting.save

  respond_to do |format|
    if @casting.save
      format.html { redirect_to @casting, notice: 'Casting was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @casting }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @casting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I use postgresql, thanks.

Comment: Could you give more information as to what the purpose of this LinkCastingToModel object is and what you are tying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you're assigning `clinet_id` to `link` from `@casting.id`, till then `@casting` was not saved, so the `id` is actually `nil`.

You'll have to call `@casting.save` before that. Then it will work. Something like this:

```
def create
  @casting = Casting.new(casting_params)
  @casting.models_booked = 0
  @casting.save
  link = LinkModelAndCasting.new
  link.client_id = @casting.id
  link.save
  # link_model_and_casting = LinkModelAndCasting.new(:casting_id => @casting.id)
  # link_model_and_casting.save

  respond_to do |format|
    if @casting.id
      format.html { redirect_to @casting, notice: 'Casting was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @casting }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @casting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```